# error while installing DBD::oracle in windows10 `perl -MCPAN -e "install DBD::Oracle"

Tags: perl, cpan

Fetching with LWP:http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz LWP failed with code[470] message[status code 470]Warning: no success downloading 'C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp16388.Giving up on it. As a last resort we now switch to the external ftp command 'C:\Windows\system32\ftp.exe' to get 'C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp16388'. I have installed oracle client, strawberry Perl and or2pg tool`

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Status code 470 is typically a firewall problem. The `cpan` command is trying to make a network connect and it's getting rejected before it even leaves your network.

How you fix that depends on what is locally configured. It needs to allow connections to `cpan.strawberryperl.com`.

You could try adjusting your CPAN config to use `www.cpan.org`, which will multiplex to an appropriate mirror for you. That host may make it through your firewall.